# Why my interceptor class doesn't work with schedule methods?

Tags: java, interceptor, ejb-3.1

I have lots of `Stateless` beans on my WildFly 10.2.0 server. Everytime I try to use `@Interceptors({LogService.class})` it works on any method, except on a `Stateless` bean that has only 2 `@Schedule(second = "*/2", minute = "*", hour = "*")` methods. I looked for documentation but didn't find any clue. Can anyone help me? I'm using Java 8.

Here's my interceptor class:

```
public class LogService {

@AroundInvoke
public Object interceptsAngLog(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {

    Long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    LocalTime now = new LocalTime();

    Object object = context.proceed();

    String method = context.getMethod().getName();
    String className = context.getTarget().getClass().getName();
    Long millisSpent = System.currentTimeMillis() - millis;

    System.out.println("[LOG] " + now.toString() + "-" + className + "-" + method + ": " + millisSpent);

    return object;
}
}
```

And here's my Schedule class:

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors({LogService.class})
public class ScoreTimerService {

@EJB
private AccountDao accountDao;

@Schedule(second = "*/3", minute = "*", hour = "*")
public void addPointsDueOnlineState() {
    List<Account> list = accountDao.findOnline();
    for (Account account : list) {
        account.addScore(5);
        accountDao.update(account);
    }
}

@Schedule(second = "*/2", minute = "*", hour = "*")
public void removePointsDueTime() {
    List<Account> list = accountDao.findAll();
    for (Account account : list) {
        account.removeScore(1);
        accountDao.update(account);
    }
}

}
```

I tried using on methods, on class, on replacing `@Interceptors({LogService.class})` for `@Interceptors(LogService.class)` but none have worked.

Comment: Can u share some code?

Comment: Sorry, I just added

Comment: are u using javax.interceptor.Interceptors annotation?

Comment: Yes, my import is like `import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptors;`

Comment: Just for testing can u remove the @Schedule annotation from one of the methods and see if its getting called. Can u try that?

Comment: One more thing make sure your interceptor class has a public, no-argument constructor.

Comment: These methods are called only because they are @Schedule. I added @Interceptors({LogService.class}) to my DAO methods and it worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157207/discussion-between-gabrielrado-and-vahid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that only `@AroundTimeout`notation works with `@Schedule` EJB Beans. So I added wrote my methods like this:

```
@AroundInvoke
public Object intercept(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
    return monitor(context);
}

@AroundTimeout
public Object interceptSchedule(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
    return monitor(context);
}

private Object monitor(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();

    String method = context.getMethod().getName();
    String className = context.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName();

    Object object = context.proceed();

    long newMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - millis;
    System.out.println("[LOG]-" + method + "." + className + "-" + newMillis + "ms");
    return object;
}
```

And it worked like a charm, for @Schedule and non @Schedule beans

Comment: You can use only one method with two annotations i.e. remove `interceptSchedule`, inline `monitor` into `intercept` and put `@AroundTimeout` on `intercept` (along with `@AroundInvoke`)